# Add an attribute to an existing element on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this div on a site, Just need to add a text automatically on page load. So I have tried Jquery append or Jquery text. But it seems they only replacing the content inside the tag.

```
<video src="how-it-works.mp4" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

I want to add a ***"controls"*** text to the video tag. Like below

```
<video controls src="how-it-works.mp4" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

Any one can help please?

Answer (score 1):

video is known tag, so have you try:

```
$("video").prop("controls", true);
```

or

```
$("video").attr("controls", "");
```

if you cant have event to trap if video is here, you could try this:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if($("video").length > 0){
       clearInterval(timer);
       $("video").attr("controls", "");
    }
}, 100);
```

every 100ms i test if tag video is present

Comment: I have tried these methods, it's not working for some reason. The tag remain same

Comment: My problem is the HTML5 player is not showing controls on hover. Users need to right-click and show controls manually. I'm trying to overcome it.

Comment: @ArshadArsal edit your question specifying your _actual_ problem and showing your attempt in a [repro]

Comment: @ArshadArsal you have to show your processus to load the page and the html , are you sure the page is loaded?

Comment: My page is on elementor. Pretty sure it is loaded. I tried the code this way
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("video").prop("control", true);
});
   

</script>

Comment: @ArshadArsal, i have modified my answer to add a function which tests when tag video is loaded, setInterval and not setTimeout